# how to remove error "[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString' "?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I am making an `sqlite3` **test3.sql** database,
making table as

```
CREATE TABLE rest (name VARCHAR(100), price VARCHAR(100));
```

table is successfully created but now when I am using a method for inserting and retrieving data, then getting error,,,

The error is on line

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                 (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

the error is `+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'`

What is this error, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of just having

```
... = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
       (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 15)]
```

You want to use something like

```
... = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 15)) ? 
      [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
       (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 15)] : nil;
```

Answer (score 5):

After using the tenary operator to get the values from the db you have to check if the value is nil. Otherwise the program will still crash.

```
NSString *retrievedString = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 15)) ? 
  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 15)] : 
  nil;

if(retrievedString == nil){
  [allSteps addObject:@""];
} else {
  [allSteps addObject:retrievedString];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that sqlite3_column_text returns NULL. It returns NULL when the column is NULL.