# How to store the Data from Parse.com to Sqlite DataBase in iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I am using parse.com to get the data like given below. I already created the data base using sqlite manager.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"movie"];

    //movie is the class name in the parse.com in that two columns store the data
    [postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //Save results and update the table
            self.postArray = objects;
            NSLog(@"array....%@",self.postArray);
            //  [spinner startAnimating];
            [self.myTable reloadData];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)getTheData:(id)sender {
    //it is sqlite query class
    model=[[DataModel alloc]init];

    //here insertQuery method to send the columns class object(buk).

    [model insertInformIntoDB:buk];

    PFObject *post = [self.postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"posttttt......%@",post);

    //here parse.com column name to send the data into sqlite Columns
    buk.name=[post objectForKey:@"name"];
    buk.Hero=[post objectForKey:@"Hero"];
}
```

I got the output like this:

//this is overall movie class

```
array....(
    "<movie:EHx3UonJmw:(null)> {\n    Hero = Mahesh;\n    name = pokiri;\n    num = 222;\n}",
    "<movie:zekgTzIsLs:(null)> {\n    Hero = pawan;\n    name = jhoni;\n    num = 412;\n}",
    "<movie:0z3ZkI4lvB:(null)> {\n    Hero = Prabhas;\n    name = darling;\n    num = 312;\n}"
)

posttttt......<movie:EHx3UonJmw:(null)> {
    Hero = Mahesh;
    name = pokiri;
    num = 222;
}
```

Error:-

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSMutableString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

but here geting null values in buk.name and Hero....

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"posttttt......%@",post);` logs?

Comment: PFObject *post = [self.postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   //here getting the data from parse.com first we get in postArray after   sending to post

Comment: Your question has become a mess now. You have exception and you also have nil values? what's your problem exception or nil vales? I think it should be exception first

Comment: Here check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968142/how-to-remove-error-nsstring-stringwithutf8string-null-cstring) help you out !..don't forget to vote if helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You question is so confusing but still I would love to show what might be wrong,
`[model insertInformIntoDB:buk];`  should be at the end of the method where you set the properties of the `buk` variable

```
-(void)getTheData:(id)sender{
  //it is sqlite query class
  model=[[DataModel alloc]init];

  //here insertQuery method to send the columns class object(buk).

  //inserting the buk without setting the values, so move this statement at the end
  //[model insertInformIntoDB:buk];


  PFObject *post = [self.postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSLog(@"posttttt......%@",post);

  //here parse.com column name to send the data into sqlite Columns
  buk.name=[post objectForKey:@"name"];
  buk.Hero=[post objectForKey:@"Hero"];

  //save the buk
  [model insertInformIntoDB:buk];
}
```

Comment: buk is the sqlite columns class: books. imported and set the property in .h file of current class